# How to declare a variable with a value from console correctly?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Good day everyone, I have this problem where I can't put value from console to a variable correctly. When I try to run it, it gives an error [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyIKK.png) but I successfully fetch the record user_id from login page to log page. I want to put the value correctly for my query but I can't. I hope you can help me.

Here's the code.

```js
  async loadUsers(){

      return new Promise(resolve => {


        this.storage.get('storage_xxx').then((res) => {
          
        let body = {
          aksi: 'load_users',
          user_id: console.log(res.user_id)
        }
        
        this.accsPrvds.postData(body, 'proses_api.php').subscribe((res:any)=>{
          for(let datas of res.result){
              this.users.push(datas);
          }
          resolve(true);
        });
      });
      });
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want that? Why can't you do like `user_id: res.user_id;`? You can print that value anytime when in scope. Console.log() does not return anything it will print data. After printing it will return `undefined` read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use directly without console log

```
let body = {
       aksi: 'load_users',
       user_id: res.user_id
}
//If you still want print that then 
console.log(res.user_id);
```